# Are there no end of line characters when using ARGF?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a csv file formatted like this:

```
Wed Mar 07 00:00:00 CET 2012,78.0
Thu Mar 08 00:00:00 CET 2012,46.0
...
```

I read it using standard input, and tried to match parts of each line using:

```
ARGF.each_line do |line|
    time << line.scan(/^\w{3} (\w{3}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) \w+ (\d{4}),([.\d]+)$/)
end
```

Which for some reason only returns the last line in the file.

If I copy the CSV file to a string variable, it starts to match each line correctly. If I remove the dollar sign from the regex it matches correctly as well, but I don't understand why `$` doesn't work when reading from ARGF. Any ideas?

Comment: Why use ARGF at all? IMO that's not really what it's for.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm a total Ruby novice; could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you have to use ARGF? You can check out the [CSV class in the standard library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html), which gives tools to make the processing easier.

Here's an example that yields one row at a time to foreach. I would guess that this allows you to not worry about where lines begin or end:

```
require "csv"

CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv") do |row|
  time << line.scan(/^\w{3} (\w{3}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) \w+ (\d{4}),([.\d]+)$/)
end
```

Comment: That looks much more convenient, thank you! But I'm still interested in knowing why '$' didn't work when using ARGF.

Comment: You gave a useful answer but to another question. We are all programming. We hack different ways, but in the end we hack up a solution to our particular problems somehow. The questions, unless explicitly stated otherwise, are usually about WHY though. In this case 'I don't understand why $ doesn't work'. An answer to the 'why' is much more appreciated and long lasting.